# Fedora doesn't boot after migration to new disk

Tags: linux, fedora, ssd

I bought a new larger SSD and copied all data from the old SSD to the new one.
On the SSD I have `Ubuntu` and `Fedora`, `Ubuntu` works normally after migration but `Fedora` boots into `Emergency Mode`. I have pasted the contents of my system output when I try to boot into `Fedora` 
[here](http://hastebin.com/fuxacolopo.vhdl).

Answer (score 1):

Despite the method you used to copy the data the dev's uuid have changed so you will need to change the boot configuration (grub I guess) and these uuid's at /etc/fstab. There are load of guides over there so ymmv

https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/31534/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-larger-hard-drive/

I have no experience with SSD specifics so I am afraid I won't be able to help you very much despite your detailed logs. Anyway these lines point out the failure reasons

`[   90.589462] fedora systemd[1]: Job dev-mapper-ssd\x2dfedora_usr.device/start timed out.
[   90.589623] fedora systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device dev-mapper-ssd\x2dfedora_usr.device.
[   90.589766] fedora systemd[1]: Dependency failed for /sysroot/usr.
[   90.589899] fedora systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Initrd File Systems.`

Check this though https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/28618/timed-out-waiting-for-device-dev-mapper-fedorax2dhomedevice/

Comment: I copied via rsync -avrogp and updated the uuid of course and I did it on the same way as at ubuntu, which works.

Comment: I found the bug, but the soultion does not work: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Common_F20_bugs#System_fails_to_boot_after_install_using_LVM_Thin_Provisioning